# HtmlUnit download link from DIV

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I'm trying to download some images from a website and they are stored in a table under div elements. I'm using Java with HtmlUnit library and this is what I have so far:

```
    _page = (HtmlPage) linkToPicsPage.click();

    List<HtmlElement> _divList = _page.getElementsByIdAndOrName("imgcontainer");

    int num = 0;
    for (HtmlElement el : _divList) {

        InputStream is = el.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
        File path = new File(_downloadPath+_car.getRegNumber());
        if (!path.exists())
            path.mkdir();
        writeToFile(is,new File(_downloadPath+_car.getRegNumber()+System.getProperty("file.separator")+_car.getRegNumber()+"["+num+"].jpg"));
        num++;
    }
```

The website code looks like this:

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceContenido_GridImagenes" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
    <div id="imgcontainer">
        <div class="imgitem">
            <a href="descarga.aspx?IDOWNER=40312&amp;ID=598477&amp;Action=View">
                <img alt="Foto Frente Izquierda" border="0" src="imgthumb.aspx?IDOWNER=40312&amp;ID=598477&amp;Action=View"/>
            </a>
            <br />
            Foto Frente Izquierda
        </div>
    </div>
</td><td>
```

But what I'm dowloading is some HTML code instead of the images themselves. I don't know how can I get the href attribute from the HtmlDivision elements that I get in "_divList". Any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit1:

This is the current code that I'm using to download them, the problem with this code is that I'm downloading some elements that I don't need (i'm downloading everything that has "descarga.aspx" in the href). That's why I want to be more specific and only download the images. As you can see, the HtmlAnchors that I get by searching for "descarga.aspx" are not redirecting me to another page:

```
    List<HtmlAnchor> picsLinks = new LinkedList<HtmlAnchor>();
    picsLinks = _page.getAnchors();
    int num = 0;
    for (HtmlAnchor currentPic : picsLinks) {
        if (currentPic.getHrefAttribute().contains("descarga.aspx")) {
            InputStream is = currentPic.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
            File path = new File(_downloadPath+_car.getRegNumber());
            if (!path.exists())
                path.mkdir();
            writeToFile(is,new File(_downloadPath+_car.getRegNumber()+System.getProperty("file.separator")+_car.getRegNumber()+"["+num+"].jpg"));
            _log.append("....Downloaded picture "+regNumber+num+".jpg\n");
            num++;
        }
        _log.setCaretPosition(_log.getDocument().getLength());
    }
```

Comment: Have ytou well checked that `descarga.aspx` directly returns the image, instead of being a redirection page ? You should ensure that using Firebug .

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question an added the old code, where you can see that I don't have any problem when I get the HtmlAnchors themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say without seeing the whole site, but I suspect it's something to do with clicking on the "imgcontainer" , which contains more than the image.   What happens when you manually click on the words "Foto Frente Izquierda" in a browser?

Try clicking on the image directly, using getByXPath and something like "//div[@class='imgitem']/a" (off the top of my head) instead of getElementsByIdAndOrName.